# how to debug gtkmm applications ( symbols from library missing )

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I want to debug my program which uses gtkmm. If I dereference a pointer to an gtkmm object, I get `incomplete type`.

I have installed `gtkmm30-debuginfo.x86_64 0:3.10.1-1.fc20`

Is there a special setting for LDFLAGS? Maybe to link against a special version of gtkmm. Which one? Maybe an other option for `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs`

Comment: I don't have RPM-based distro at hand right now, but does this doc help? https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html#Separate-Debug-Files

Comment: You can always build everything on your own with symbols. I've done that some time ago and it wasn't nice... Even with *tutorial* on the internet.